# Merging duplicates and adding differences without using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I have a data set (I will just write an example below) that I need to merge duplicates and add differences onto the same line. Also with that I need to take a column and use its values a new header column to tally those duplicates.

---

[image: Example Data]

So basically, the idea is to use input data like the left side and create condensed data on the right WITHOUT VBA. If it can be done that is?

EDIT: Basically, what I need to do is combine like items (by using the ID since that is a unique identifier) and then on the same row add additional things like the count of how many tickets are opened in that and such. Its hard to put into words but basically transform the left table into the right using formulas.

Comment: use a Pivot table.

Comment: You can do =text.concatenate(...;...;...) to merge cells together, but other than that, I don't know what exactly your question is.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/918639/jlolslh) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/918642/jlolslh). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Did my suggestion below help?

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table is the quickest, and likeliest best way.  But if you really need formulas, you can use `COUNTIFS()`.  The data in grey is "hard coded", the other info is the same formula.  You can put this in `J2`, drag over and down:

```
=COUNTIFS(ID,$G2,First,$H2,Last,$I2,TicketName,J$1)
```

[image]

The named ranges are simply the values from the table:

[image]